# Why does one hot encoding add paranthesis and commas when joining dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

After I performed onehotencoding, I want to join the new columns into the old dataframe. But when I do that, the new columns have parentheses and commas. Is this a OHE or pandas problem? Is there a way to fix this?

This code generates an example dataframe

```
d = {'col': ['a','b','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
    col
0   a
1   b
2   c
```

This code creates the encoder and shows the new encoded dataframe

```
# Create encoder
enc = ohe()

# Create variable to store fitted and transformed encoder
temp = enc.fit_transform(df[['col3']]).toarray()

# Get labels
labels = enc.categories_

# Create 'features' dataframe
features = pd.DataFrame(temp, columns = labels)

# Concatenate 'features' dataframe with df
df_enc = pd.concat([df, features], axis = 1)

# Drop 'education' column
df_enc = df_enc.drop('col3', axis = 1)

df_enc.head()

    (a,)(b,)(c,)
0   1.0 0.0 0.0
1   0.0 1.0 0.0
2   0.0 0.0 1.0
```

Is there a way to remove the parantheses and commas?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your original table as python code so that it's easy to reproduce and thus easy to help you :-)

Comment: Also, at first glance the formatting of your column names seems to be due to your second command `.toarray()`.

Comment: My data is actually from a csv file so im not sure how to create a new dataframe for you

Comment: You could use `df1.to_dict()` and paste the output :-)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for you replies but i changed the question. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add [0] to

```
# Get labels
labels = enc.categories_
```

So now it is

```
# Get labels
labels = enc.categories_[0]
```